# Prove inequality of complex objects

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a pair of maps that are trivially incompatible. I'm wondering what's the graceful/automatized way to get a proof of it.

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.

(* Prelude: the total_map data structure from Software Foundations, slightly modified *)
Definition total_map := string -> nat.
Definition empty_st : total_map := (fun _ => 0).
Definition t_update (m : total_map) k v := fun k' => if string_dec k k' then v else m k'.
Notation "a '!->' x" := (t_update empty_st a x) (at level 100).
Notation "x '!->' v ';' m" := (t_update m x v) (at level 100, v at next level, right associativity).

(* The actual goal I'm trying to solve *)
Definition X: string := "X".
Definition Y: string := "Y".
Goal forall n, (X !-> n; Y !-> n) <> (X !-> 1; Y !-> 2).
Proof.
  intros n contra.
  remember (X !-> n; Y !-> n) as st.
  remember (st X) as n1.
  assert (n1 = n). { rewrite Heqn1; rewrite Heqst; cbv; reflexivity. }
  assert (n1 = 1). { rewrite Heqn1; rewrite contra; cbv; reflexivity. }
  remember (st Y) as n2.
  assert (n2 = n). { rewrite Heqn2; rewrite Heqst; cbv; reflexivity. }
  assert (n2 = 2). { rewrite Heqn2; rewrite contra; cbv; reflexivity. }
  congruence.
Qed.
```

Comment: What are `!->`? (I mean could you provide all the definitions so the snippet compiles?)

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: This seems to be a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662000/2747511

Answer (score 2):

In order to automate this, you need to have a precise description of your proof strategy.  Here is one possible proof strategy:

To prove an inequality of `total_map`s:

1. First introduce the equality hypothesis.
2. Then, for every key that's been added to either map, add the hypothesis that the value associated to that key is the same in both maps.
3. Then simplify all such equality hypotheses by unfolding `t_update`, using that `string_dec x x` is true, and seeing if any other `string_dec`s compute down.
4. Finally, solve the goal by `congruence`.

We can automate each of these steps.  Altogether, it becomes:

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.

(* Prelude: the total_map data structure from Software Foundations, slightly modified *)
Definition total_map := string -> nat.
Definition empty_st : total_map := (fun _ => 0).
Definition t_update (m : total_map) k v := fun k' => if string_dec k k' then v else m k'.
Notation "a '!->' x" := (t_update empty_st a x) (at level 100).
Notation "x '!->' v ';' m" := (t_update m x v) (at level 100, v at next level, right associativity).

(* Automation *)

(* 1. First introduce the equality hypothesis. *)
Ltac start_proving_inequality H :=
  intro H.

(* 2. Then, for every key that's been added to either map, add the hypothesis that the value associated to that key is the same in both maps. *)
(* To do this, we need a tactic that will pose a proof only if it does not already exist. *)
Ltac unique_pose_proof lem :=
  let T := type of lem in
  lazymatch goal with
  | [ H : T |- _ ] => fail 0 "A hypothesis of type" T "already exists"
  | _ => pose proof lem
  end.

(* Maybe move this elsewhere? *)
Definition t_get (m : total_map) k := m k.

Ltac saturate_with_keys H :=
  repeat match type of H with
         | context[t_update _ ?k ?v]
           => unique_pose_proof (f_equal (fun m => t_get m k) H)
         end.

(* 3. Then simplify all such equality hypotheses by unfolding `t_update`, using that `string_dec x x` is true, and seeing if any other `string_dec`s compute down. *)
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.
Lemma string_dec_refl x : string_dec x x = left eq_refl.
Proof.
  destruct (string_dec x x); [ apply f_equal | congruence ].
  apply UIP_dec, string_dec.
Qed.

(* N.B. You can add more cases here to deal with other sorts of ways you might reduce [t_get] here *)
Ltac simplify_t_get_t_update_in H :=
  repeat first [ progress cbv [t_get t_update empty_st] in H
               | match type of H with
                 | context[string_dec ?x ?x] => rewrite (string_dec_refl x) in H
                 | context[string_dec ?x ?y]
                   => let v := (eval cbv in (string_dec x y)) in
                      (* check that it fully reduces *)
                      lazymatch v with left _ => idtac | right _ => idtac end;
                      progress change (string_dec x y) with v in H
                 end ].

Ltac simplify_t_get_t_update :=
  (* first we must change hypotheses of the form [(fun m => t_get m k) m = (fun m => t_get m k) m'] into [t_get _ _ = t_get _ _] *)
  cbv beta in *;
  repeat match goal with
         | [ H : t_get _ _ = t_get _ _ |- _ ] => progress simplify_t_get_t_update_in H
         end.

(* 4. Finally, solve the goal by `congruence`. *)
Ltac finish_proving_inequality := congruence.

(* Now we put it all together *)
Ltac prove_total_map_inequality :=
  let H := fresh in
  start_proving_inequality H;
  saturate_with_keys H;
  simplify_t_get_t_update;
  finish_proving_inequality.

(* The actual goal I'm trying to solve *)
Definition X: string := "X".
Definition Y: string := "Y".
Goal forall n, (X !-> n; Y !-> n) <> (X !-> 1; Y !-> 2).
  intros.
  prove_total_map_inequality.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jason Gross's answer and the fact that `total_map` is a decidable type, I've put together a bit of automation to deal with this. Note that this problem would probably be a very good fit for small-scale reflection.

```
(* TODO: don't bring trivial (n = n) or duplicated hypotheses into scope *)

(* Given two maps left and right, plus a lemma that they are equal, plus some key: assert that the values of the maps agree at the specified key *)
Ltac invert_total_map_equality_for_id lemma left right id :=
  let H := fresh "H" in
  assert (left id = right id) as H by (rewrite lemma; reflexivity); 
  cbv in H.

(* Recurse on the LHS map, extracting keys *)
Ltac invert_total_map_equality_left lemma left right left_remaining :=
  match left_remaining with
  | t_update ?left_remaining' ?id _ =>
    invert_total_map_equality_for_id lemma left right id;
    invert_total_map_equality_left lemma left right left_remaining'
  | _ => idtac
  end.

(* Recurse on the RHS map, extracting keys; move on to LHS once we've done all RHS keys *)
Ltac invert_total_map_equality_right lemma left right right_remaining :=
  match right_remaining with
  | t_update ?right_remaining' ?id _ =>
    invert_total_map_equality_for_id lemma left right id;
    invert_total_map_equality_right lemma left right right_remaining'
  | _ => invert_total_map_equality_left lemma left right left
  end.

(* Given a lemma that two total maps are equal, assert that their values agree at each defined key *)
Ltac invert_total_map_equality lem :=
  let T := type of lem in
    match T with
    | ?left = ?right =>
      match type of left with
      | string -> nat =>
        match type of right with
        | string -> nat =>
          invert_total_map_equality_right lem left right right
      end
    end
  end.

Goal forall n, (X !-> n; Y !-> n) <> (X !-> 1; Y !-> 2).
Proof.
  unfold not; intros.
  invert_total_map_equality H.
  congruence.
Qed.
```